# Regex for Accepting any number of Characters and -

Tags: javascript, regex

Can any one give me correct Regular Expression to accept Name starting with characters and ending with characters, in middle i can allow -
Ex: ABC or ABC-DEF or ABC-DEF-GHI 
But it should not start or end with -
Ex: -ABC or -ABC- or ABC-

Here is my Regular Expression:

```
var regex = /^[A-Za-z]-?[A-Za-z]*-?([A-Za-z]+)+$/
```

This works perfactly fine for me, but if suppose i want to give name as AB-CD-EF-GH than this don't work.
Note: Remember that Name should start with Characters and End with Characters and in between i can have - but not -- twice. It has to be associated with characters like a-b-c-d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.*` inside to allow any number of any characters except for a newline:

```
var regex = /^(?!.*--.*$)[A-Za-z].*[A-Za-z]$/
```

`(?!.*--.*$)` will make sure double hyphens are not allowed.

Please check the [regex demo here](https://regex101.com/r/iE1wJ8/2).

```js
function ValIt(str) 
{
   var re = /^(?!.*?--.*?$)[A-Za-z].*[A-Za-z]$/g; 
   if ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) 
       return true;
     else
       return false;
}

document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = 'RTT--rrtr: ' + ValIt('RTT--rrtr') + "<br>ER#$-wrwr: "+ ValIt('ER#$-wrwr') + "<br>Rfff-ff-d: " + ValIt('Rfff-ff-d');
```

```html
<div id=res />
```

Comment: It should not allow multiple hyphen together like ABC--EFG, it should repeat like this abc-efg-hij-esd. Also it can only contain characters without any hyphen like ABC. Alternative hyphen should be optional

Comment: @Rajesh: Can you please check the code now? If you use `--` in the negative look-ahead, only successive hyphens will be disallowed.

Comment: @Rajesh you dont need lookahead for this question.It can be done simply.`Lookaheads` are expensive

Answer (score 1):

```
^[A-Za-z]+(?:-[A-Za-z]+)*$
```

This simple regex will do it for you.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/sJ9gM7/55

```
var re = /^[A-Za-z]+(?:-[A-Za-z]+)*$/gim;
var str = 'ABC\nABC-DEF\n-ABC\nABC-\nAB-CD-EF-GH\n';
var m;

if ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
re.lastIndex++;
}
// View your result using the m-variable.
// eg m[0] etc.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you want :

```
  /^[A-Z](-[A-Z]+)*[A-Z]$/i
```

Analysis :

```
  /^       Start of string
  [A-Z]    Any alphabetic character
  (        Group
    -        A hyphen character
    [A-Z]+   One or more alphabetic characters
  )*       0 or more repititons of group
  [A-Z]    Any alphabetic character
  $/i      End of string, allow upper or lower case alpha
```

Comment: This match also `"AB--CD"`

Comment: Thank U for the explanation... Helped me to understand better

Answer (score 0):

```
var rgx = /^[A-Za-z]+(-[A-Za-z]+)*$/;

rgx.test("ABC"); // true
rgx.test("ABC-DEF"); // true
rgx.test("AB-CD-EF-GH"); // true
rgx.test("-AB-CD-EF-GH"); // false
rgx.test("AB-CD-"); // false
rgx.test("AB--CD"); // false
```